# Segment Local Stable Manifold versus Line Global Stable Manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, manifolds, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

In a given context of a couple of ODE's, it's proved that the local stable manifold through one equilibrium point is a vertical segment, once we have by calculus that it's tangent to $[0,1]$ and has dimension $1$.

I was thinking if there's some result that allows us to extend local to global stable manifold and say that **the global stable manifold  through this equilibrium point is the vertical line (of $\mathbb{R}^2$) through it**. Is it possible?

If not, could you give some counterexample or explain why?

Many thanks.

***EDIT: Once the question seems to vague, please, could you so reference some good (and relatively simple - I mean, MsC Level) for extend results to local stable manifolds to global stable manifolds?***

Comment: I don't understand your question. It seems to be missing some context? I don't know about which system you are talking about, what is "Segment local X" or anything. What "certain given question"? What dynamical system? What vertical line (what is the ambiant space)?

Comment: @DIdier_, sorry. The $X$ is just versus, I'll change. "Certain given certain" is one question that a person solved and for various reasons I could not post here. I'll try fix something

Comment: @DIdier_ please could you review? Thank you

Comment: Your question is really just too vague. Perhaps a question about local stable manifolds of  an explicit ODE might work, but as it stands it seems unanswerable to me.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you and sorry. I wrote an EDIT: Once the question seems to vague, please, could you so reference some good (and relatively simple - I mean, MsC Level) for extend results to local stable manifolds to global stable manifolds?

Comment: @DIdier_ Thank you and sorry. I wrote an EDIT: Once the question seems to vague, please, could you so reference some good (and relatively simple - I mean, MsC Level) for extend results to local stable manifolds to global stable manifolds?