# A continuous and derivable decreasing function s.t. the derivative is $0$ for $t>t_0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, functions, derivatives, monotone-functions

The question may be silly, but I am stucked with this thought...

I ask for a **nonconstant continuous and derivable nondecreasing function** s.t. **the derivative approaches $0$ for $t\to\infty$, but more than that I might have $f'(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0$ and also for all $t>t_0$.**

I really cannot think this example. For instance, $f(t)=\text{log}(t)$ does not mind, because $f'$ approaches to $0$, but $f'(t)\neq0\forall t$. And so on.

But because this question?

Because I have an equation on a model of form $\dfrac{d f}{d t}=g(t)$ with $g(t)$ nonpositive and I might have $g(t)=0$ for all $t>t_0$ for some $t_0>0$, but I cannot realize this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: To be sure, what you're asking for is a non-constant, non-decreasing, differetiable function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ subject to the additional property that $f'(t) =0$ for all $t  \geq t_0$ for some $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Is that right?

Comment: Right @ThomasWinckelman!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=-x^2$ when $x\le 0$ and $f(x)=0$, when $x>0$.

Comment: Really! So with a little bit more of argumentation, maybe I can state that this can occur $\iff \lim_{t\to t_0^-}f'(t)=0$?Thank you so much.

Comment: Perfect example Alex.

Comment: @Quiet_waters I guess in the first comment you asked something like “$f$ is a nonconstant continuous and derivable nondecreasing function s.t. the derivative approaches $0$ for $t\to\infty$, but more than that I might have $f'(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0$ and also for all $t>t_0$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\lim_{t\to t_0^-} f’(t)=0$ and some conditions hold"?

Comment: @AlexRavsky yes, I mean, is it possible that I can have $f'(t)=0$ for all $t>t_0$ on these conditions iff I have $\lim_{t\to t_0^-} f'(t)=0$ (so the derivative is continuous and $f$ is derivable anywhere)...(?) Thank you so much

Comment: @AlexRavsky I am sorry by the other comment, $x²$ would be if I've wrote nonincreasing. I've deleted. When the system accept, I'll bounty your answer. Many thanks

Comment: @Quiet_waters Do you mean the following? Let $f$ be a nonconstant continuous and derivable nondecreasing function s.t. the derivative approaches $0$ for $t\to\infty$. Then $f'(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0$ and also for all $t>t_0$” $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\lim_{t\to t_0^-} f’(t)=0$.

Comment: Yes...!@AlexRavsky

Comment: @AlexRavsky maybe you could help us with the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3986460/577356. Thank you!

Comment: @Quiet_waters Unfortunately, I am weak in all domains, corresponding to the tags of that question. :-(

Comment: @Quiet_waters For a counterexample for $\Leftarrow$ see Salcio’s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988036/a-continuous-and-derivable-decreasing-function-s-t-the-derivative-is-0-for-t/3988117#3988117). A counterxample for $\Rightarrow$ is a function $f(t)=t-t^2(1+sin(1/t))$ when $t<0$ and $f(t)=0$, when $t\ge 0$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky, thank you so much. The function $f(t)=t-t^2(1+\sin(1/t))$ is derivable on $0$? I was thinking... I feel that this question has relation with Finite-time stability for time-varying dynamical systems. Well, thank you also for comment about the other question anyway. 3 hours laters the system will bounty your example here. Best regards.

Comment: @Quiet_waters Oops, it is not derivable at $0$, sorry. Thanks for your attention. I have to think more about the implication $\Rightarrow$.

Answer (score 1):

The constant function f(x)=2 (say) satisfies all your requirements.

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer?

Comment: Thank you, Lawrence, however I've asked for some "nonconstant" as I've wrote. What do you think? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $$f(x) = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{sin^{2}t}{t}dt$$
Since integral measures area below the graph and since the function being integrated is non-negative $f(x)$ is increasing. Of course, derivative of $f(x)$ is $\frac{sin^{2}x}{x}$ and it non-negative and is zero at $k*\pi$.

Comment: Thank you, Salcio! However I ask derivative zero for all points from some, you see...$\forall t>t_0$

Comment: Actually, you say $f^{'}(t_{0}) = 0$ (not $f^{'}(t) = 0$). But if you change the problem as you suggest then it becomes trivial since zero derivative from some point on implies that function is constant from this point on.

Comment: sorry, maybe because my language is not native I did not write fine. But I said "$f'(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0$ and for $t>t_0$". I've edited with more property (I hope). Thank you anytime. However, I did not understand why is trivial in this case, because I could not yet conceive a differenciable function on this case! (all that I thought is not differenciable on $t_0$). If you could post one example, I'll be glad to accept it. Thank you so much!